# Mixing jest expect with detox expect

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

How to mix Jest expect with Detox expect? Here is what I try to do. It seem `expect` has overrided the jest `expect`.

```
await mockServer.mockAnyResponse({
    httpRequest: {
      method: 'POST', 
      path: '/api/register',
    },
    httpResponse: {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: 'xxx',
      }),
    }
});

await element(by.id('name')).typeText('Robert');
await element(by.id('password')).typeText('123456');
await element(by.id('register')).tap();

// Check if endpoint has been called
let result = await mockServer.checkIfRegisterEndPointHasBeenCalled();
expect(result).toBe(true); // <-- how to do something like this?
```

Comment: did you find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

This is done in two steps:

1. When you use `detox.init()`,  pass a false `initGlobals` parameter, e.g.: `detox.init({ initGlobals: false })`. This will disable overriding global vars like `expect` of Jest.
2. Use detox public variables through `const { device, expect } = require('detox');` or a similar ES6 import.

Comment: ES6 import is still not supported in node, you'll have to Babel your tests for that, which greatly complicates setup.

Comment: The documentation shows `detox.init(config, {initGlobals: false});`. Does that have the same outcome as `detox.init({ initGlobals: false })`, or is one of them wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to ignore the fact that Detox overwrote `expect`, and re-import Jest's `expect` under a different name.

`const jestExpect = require('expect');`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is obvious to a more experienced "tester", but the two other answers are only partially correct, and are missing something that I had a bit of trouble with: you get `undefined` when you try to access or `require` `expect` globally, you have to do that within the test.

So you'll have to do the following:
In the `init.js` file:

```
before(async () => {
  await detox.init(config, {initGlobals: false});
});
```

In your test file - either the actual `it` (with `const`) or the `before` (with `let jestExpect` in the `describe`):

```
jestExpect = require('expect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's can be done in .detoxrc.js by adding behavior object as described in detox docs

https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/19.x/config/overview#behavior-configuration

If you do not wish to leak Detox globals (expect, device, by, etc.) to the global scope, you can set "exposeGlobals": false and destructure them respectively from the exported Detox interface:

```
import {by, device, expect as detoxExpect, element} from 'detox';
```

Jest's expect will work as usual

Answer (score 0):

With Jest v29.5, you will need to use `const { expect: jestExpect } = require('expect');` instead of `const jestExpect = require('expect');`